# Maximum call stack size exceeded in socket.io-redis and heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, socket.io-1.0, koa

I'm trying to use socket.io in my application. I saw that i need to use socket.io-redis to fix my problem with multiple dynos. But when I try to use redis-cloud and socket.io-redis I keep getting "**Maximum call stack size exceeded**". Below is my code

```
io.adapter(redis({
  pubClient: require("redis").createClient(PORT, HOST, {return_buffers: true}),
  subClient: require("redis").createClient(PORT, HOST, {return_buffers: true})
}));
```

I also use koa-session-redis for my session

```
koa.use(session({
                  store: {
                     host: HOST,
                     port: PORT
                 }
               }))
```

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer since I had the same error in a very different configuration, but in my case I found the error was coming from the `msgpack` module, msgpack.js, lines 465 & 466 of the `sizeof` method:

```
if('function' === typeof value.toJSON)
    return sizeof(value.toJSON());
```

Is it possible you are pushing out an object on your socket that implements toJSON in such a way that there is a self-reference or a circular reference?